# Create anonymous LINQ Lambda sort expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I create a generic method which can take in a **sortExpression** based on **MyObject** properties, something like this :

```
void CreateSortedReport(IList<MyObject> list, Expression<Func<MyObject, TSort>> sortExpression, bool ascending = true) 
{
    //sort the [list] by sortExpression and by direction;
}
```

so that I can use it like this:

```
CreateSortedReport(myItems, x=>x.Name);
```

or

```
CreateSortedReport(myItems, x=>x.CreateDate);
```

Edit 1:
The reason I ask for generic method since there are some methods which are very similar:

```
CreateReportSortedByName(myItems) {
    return myItems.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
}

CreateReportSortedByDate(myItems) {
    return myItems.OrderBy(x=>x.CreateDate);
}
```

Comment: @DioPhung, if you're operating on `IList<T>`, you can substitute your expression monad with `Func<MyObject, TSort>`.

Comment: @sstan: That's right, I want to do an in-place sort inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `MyObject` is a concrete type, simply add a single generic parameter (`<TSort>`) to your method signature:

```
void CreateReport<TSort>(IList<MyObject> list, Expression<Func<MyObject, TSort>> sortExpression, bool ascending = true)
```

If you want `MyObject` to be a generic parameter, your signature will look like this:

```
void CreateReport<MyObject, TSort>(IList<MyObject> list, Expression<Func<MyObject, TSort>> sortExpression, bool ascending = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the inbuilt sort function to provide an in-place sort, you'd need to write a class that implements `IComparer<T>`.

For example:

```
class CompareWithDelegate<TOnObject, TSort> : IComparer<TOnObject>
{
    Func<TOnObject, TSort> evaluator;
    IComparer comparer = Comparer.Default;
    bool ascending;
    public CompareWithDelegate(Expression<Func<TOnObject, TSort>> expr, bool ascending = true)
    {
        evaluator = expr.Compile();
        this.ascending = ascending;
    }
    public int Compare(TOnObject left, TOnObject right)
    {
        var leftVal = evaluator(left);
        var rightVal = evaluator(right);
        return (ascending ? 1 : -1) * comparer.Compare(leftVal, rightVal);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
void CreateSortedReport<TSort>(List<MyObject> list, Expression<Func<MyObject, TSort>> sortExpression, bool ascending = true) 
{
    list.Sort(new CompareWithDelegate<MyObject, TSort>(sortExpression));
    list.Dump();    
}
```

Note that the `list` must be `List<MyObject>`, not `IList<MyObject>`.

Alternatively, if you don't need it to be in-place, you have two options:

Change the signature to `Func<MyObject, TSort>`:

```
void CreateSortedReport<TSort>(List<MyObject> list, Func<MyObject, TSort> sortExpression, bool ascending = true) 
{
    var t = 
        ascending 
        ? list.OrderBy (sortExpression)
        : list.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
}
```

Or compile the expression on the fly:

```
void CreateSortedReport<TSort>(List<MyObject> list, Expression<Func<MyObject, TSort>> sortExpression, bool ascending = true) 
{
    var method = sortExpression.Compile();
    var t = 
        ascending 
        ? list.OrderBy (method)
        : list.OrderByDescending(method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an extension method base on the built-in [List(of T).Sort(IComparer(of T))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public static class SortExtension
{
    public static void SortBy<T, TProperty>(this List<T> list, Func<T, TProperty> orderby, bool ascending = true)
    {
        list.Sort(new InnerComparer<T, TProperty>(orderby, ascending));
    }

    class InnerComparer<T, TProperty> : IComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, TProperty> _property;
        private readonly int _ascending;

        public InnerComparer(Func<T, TProperty> property, bool ascending)
        {
            _property = property;
            _ascending = ascending ? 1 : -1;
        }

        int IComparer<T>.Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            var p1 = _property(x);
            var p2 = _property(y);

            return _ascending * Comparer<TProperty>.Default.Compare(p1, p2);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
myObjects.SortBy(o => o.MyProperty);
```